# AWS Lambda: return type String is not compatible with POJOClass

Tags: java, aws-lambda, lombok

I am trying to return String from the handleRequest. I generate String from JSON using GSON.

Here's the method:

```
public String handleRequest(Map<String, String> input, Context context){
    final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();

    String json;

    //other logic here

    json = gson.toJson(myPOJOResponseClass);
    return json
}
```

I am getting this error: return type String is not compatible with myPOJOResponseClass

I tried to change the return type to Object didn't work. I tried to convert the String to JSON explicitly using JSONObject and changed the return type to JSONObject as well but that is not working either.

Any help would be appreciated.

PS: I am generating my POJO class using Lombok if that matters here.

Comment: you're calling `gson.toJson()` with `myPOJOResponseClass`. Are you sure you don't want to call it with `input` ?

Comment: I would like to call to convert myPOJOResponseClass to JSON and return it.

Comment: And what are the fields of class `myPOJOResponseClass` ? please create [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please post the code that implements the `RequestHandler` interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't provided much code for context, but based on the docs it looks like you have probably done something like this:

```
public class HelloPojo implements RequestHandler<Map<String, String>, myPOJOResponseClass>
```

Which would then mean that to implement the interface, your `handleRequest(...)` function needs to return `myPOJOResponseClass`.

If that is what is going on, try this:

```
public class HelloPojo implements RequestHandler<Map<String, String>, String>
```

Comment: My bad I missed this. Yes it helped and this was exactly the error. Thank you.